# Python string slice step?

Tags: python, string, slice

I want to convert python codes to java. But I do not understand slicing step parameter.

Example:

```py
x = "Hello World !"
x[6:2:-1]
```

And what is the result **x[6:2:-1]** ?

Comment: Why don't you execute it and see?

Comment: I do not installed python libraries etc...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual?

Comment: Instead of converting your python code to java, why don't you host it in jython? You'll save yourself a lot of time.

Comment: Also, as a minimum, you should be able to run python to complete this project. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: The basic format (which is quite common and present in every single programming language I can think of) is start:end:step. It helps to specify the parameters for an implicit loop.

Comment: The code runs in every installed python interpreter. so "I do not installed python libraries" is a very lame excuse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-1` step just reverts the direction of the slice:

```
>>> x = "Hello World !"
>>> x[6]
'W'
>>> x[2]
'l'
>>> x[6:2:-1]
'W ol'
```

`[6:2:-1]` means give me a slice from the 6th to the 2nd item (not including), reversed.

FYI, you don't need python installed for checking the result of the code you've asked about, go to [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) and play:

> PythonAnywhere is a Python development and hosting environment that
>   displays in your web browser and runs on our servers.

Also see:

- [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)
- [Extended Slices](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/whatsnew/section-slices.html)